# What to do if I missed some important details in my question

Tags: discussion, questions

One week ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33056101/581205), where I missed the fact that there's no 1:1 relationship between `main` and `second`. The SQL should  contain `ON second.mainId = main.id AND second.fourth = ?`, which completely invalidates [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057401/581205) (while [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057401/581205) seems to be too general to tell).

What's the proper action now? Edit or delete and ask again? If there were no answers, it'd be easy....

Comment: Is the change relevant to the core question you're asking, if so, how is it relevant?

Comment: @Servy As I wrote, it invalidates one IMHO useful answer (I learnt something from it) and it's a rather different problem now. I guess, no matter how good an answer to the original question may be, it can't help me with what I really want to know.

Comment: If the edit would invalidate an existing answer that does answer the question that was asked, i'd go with asking anew, and leaving the old.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you simply didn't ask the question that you had intended to ask, leave the existing question alone and ask the question that you now realize you ought to have asked.

While the original question may not have been what you really wanted to know, as long as it's an appropriate, on topic, and sensible question, you should leave it.  Someone else may benefit from it, even if you wouldn't.

Had the answer simply misunderstood the question *that you were asking all along*, then editing the question to *better clarify what it has always been* would be okay, even though the result it that it becomes clearer to readers that the answer misunderstands the question.  In your case though, since the problem is not a misunderstood question, but an improperly asked question, this would not be appropriate.

Comment: +1 for the clearest distinction I've read between *answerer* misunderestimationating and *asker* confusticationatory, and the very different courses of action to take on the question accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd add that when the OP asks the revised question — the one that s/he intended to ask but didn't — it would be good to include (probably near the bottom) a mention of (and link to) the original question, plus a quick explanation of why the new question is different from the original.  It will make life easier for those who recognize the new one as very similar to the old one, and will save them having to work out what the difference is.