# What to do if I added incomplete details, making the answers useless for my needs, but correct considering my incomplete details?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I have posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674425/subquery-to-count-items-and-then-group-them-by-a-field-of-the-main-query-withou?noredirect=1#comment101796225_57674425) and mentionned some details about my needs. 
People answered with a way that could work if you read my question as it is, but after reading their answer I realized my details were incomplete, and it makes makes the answers useless for me.

- Should I edit the question and take out my mentionning of these details, so the answers become valid, and then open a new question with correct explanations?
- Should I edit the post to complete the details, which would make the answers a bit off-topic?
- Or should I just add my details in the comments to the answer and keep the question as is?

Note that I am aware of this question: [What to do if I missed some important details in my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307981/what-to-do-if-i-missed-some-important-details-in-my-question). It is pretty close, but in my case I did provide part of the details, I was just not specific enough.

Comment: You should never edit a question when your edit will invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Understood. So I should remove my mention of the details to make them completely valid, and ask another question then?

Comment: Why would removing specific details invalidate the question for you?

Comment: @fbueckert No, that's not it. What I meant is that I mentionned I wanted a subquery so I could gather additional information in the same query, but the thing is I didn't mention it was a SUM that I was using, which makes the JOINs (as suggested in the answers) invalid, because the data in my SUMs would be different then.

Comment: Can you alter the subquery to do what you need, based on the information you received?

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think I can, it would still be wrong because I'm making a sum of the subquery. But anyway, it fits the way I asked the question so I'm going to accept the answer.

Comment: @JoeyQuint: As an aside, I appreciate that you asked this question. It demonstrates care about improving the quality of the content, while simultaneously respecting the time and effort contributed in good faith for the existing answers. I think a lot of contributors with only a few questions under their belt would have simply edited the question—or, even worse, downvoted correct answers that didn't address their unvoiced question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have received answers for the question you asked. You have now realised that you needed to ask a different question. So "close" this question by accepting a useful answer, learn something from this, and let future visitors learn something from it.

Then go forth and ask a new question, the actual question that you needed to ask.

To preempt duplicate votes, include a short sentence about what distinguishes the new question from the old one (with a reference to it).